# Query easyaudit middleware model in Django

Tags: django, django-middleware

I'm using easyaudit to audit my Django CRUD and login operations. I would like to be able to access the easyaudit models with graphene queries so I can hook up to my frontend properly.

I'm not even sure how to import the models from middleware? How do I do that?

Comment: Use the regular `import` mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the GitHub page and code, `django-easy-audit` uses regular database models to store its info. The models can be found in the file https://github.com/soynatan/django-easy-audit/blob/master/easyaudit/models.py

To access the data directly, you could query these models directly like this:

```
from easyaudit.models import CRUDEvent, LoginEvent, RequestEvent
CRUDEvent.objects.filter()
```

I am not sure how you plan to integrate this with `Graphene`; I would need more info to guide you there.